# how to SELECT based on an attribute of the column name?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to extract from a table based on the column names, the column names have to  meet a certain condition.

here is the pseudo code of what I want to do :

```
SELECT <COLUMNS> 
FROM <TABLE>
WHERE SUBSTR(<COLUMNS>, 1, 3) IN ('ADC','ERT', 'RTY')
```

is there a way I could do this?

Comment: dynamic SQL - build your statements in a loop and execute dynamically

Comment: You are going to do this via PL/SQL.  You'll query all_tab_columns by table_name to get the columns you want.  Then, use the results to dynamically build the SQL query you needs against that table.  This is pretty common.  Why don't you take a stab at it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this but remember I think this works on Oracle DB.

select COLUMN_NAME from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='YOUR_TABLE_NAME' and substr(column_name,1,4) in ('LAST','FIRS','EXAM');

Thanks

Comment: thanx for the answer, by my question relates to the data bot the column names, I want to use the attributes of the column names to extract the data from those columns.